# Input not focusing on click in bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, modal-dialog

I'm in front of a problem i can't solve by myself.
I'm using a jquery colorpicker (spectrum) in a bootstrap modal box, but, when i do so, the input in the colorPicker can't be focused on when i click on it. The mouse cursor appears, but nothing happens, so i can't change the input value.

When it is not in a modal box, it works perfectly.

Here's a url to test the problem : http://www.fgtechs.fr/widget-app/

Why can't i select the input when it's in the modal box, and how can i solve it ?

Thank's for all ;)

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following script(.coffee), it would solve the problem.

```
$(document).on 'focusin', '.sp-container', (e) ->
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```